# LDPC encoder with rate 3/4

Tags: coding-theory

If an LDPC encoder with code rate 3/4 was used and parity check matrix of dimension $H=168$ rows $\times 672$ columns is used, is it correct to say that the maximum number of information bits in each LDPC codeword is 168 bits?

I think the answer is wrong as $\frac{k}{n}= \frac{3}{4}= \frac{504}{672}$
and therefore the maximum number of bits is 504.

Update:

1) If 168 bits instead of 504 bits are used with 3/4 code rate, why is the effective rate with shorteneing equal to 1/2?

2) what is the difference between systematic and non systematic LDPC coders?

Comment: Hi. I am curious of which book you are using.

Comment: it is actually not a book but an application that used LDPC codes and I am basically trying to verify why they used bits of this length @mathreadler

Comment: Ok I got curious to read up on it. Maybe I should check wikipedia or some pdf online.

Comment: If the code is rate 3/4, then it is **exactly** 504 data bits (not *maximum number*). Some application may call for shortening of the code (=setting a known subset of information bits to zero), but that won't change the fact that encoding using this will need 504 info bits to produce those 168 check bits. If the check matrix were systematic, you could do with less (discarding the columns were the payload is known to be zero).

Comment: Thanks, in your opinion, when setting info bits to 168, i.e performing shortening, what is the effective rate, it is not 3/4 ofcourse, is it 1/4 or 1/2?@JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: 1/2 sure. But to do shortening you should have means to do systematic encoding. Have you got one? This is a relatively short LDPC code, so you can just do Gaussian elimination. A more important concern is that LDPC code might work better when inserting the zeros at carefully chosen positions. Determining those is not easy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, if I may ask why is 1/2? The data bits used is 168 which is 1/4 of 672. Why isnt the code rate 1/4 then? thanks

Comment: When you shorten the code by using only 168 out of the 504 possible data bits, you set the remaining 336 data bits all to zero. And you throw them away, so the code becomes shorter. Its length drops from 672 to 336.

Comment: May I ask one more question, what is the purpose of using LDPC 3/4 with shortening, why not use LDPC code rate 1/2. Obviously there is advantages, I want to clairfy what are they? thank you